# Перестановка последовательности в начало массива

Tags: c++-cli

Необходимо переписать в начало массива группу, содержащую наибольшее число подряд идущих положительных элементов. Не могу разобрать что тут нужно переделать. Программа на с++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    const int n = 10;
    int a[n], i, p1, p2, temp, j;
    int k = 0;
    int max = 0;

    cout << "Vvedite massiv" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] > 0) {
            ++k;
        } else {
            if (k > max) {
                max = k;
                p2 = i - 1;
                p1 = p2 - k + 1;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << " itogov massiv " << endl;

    for (i = p1; i <= p2; i++) {
        for (j = p1; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
            a[j + 1] = temp;

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ' ' << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: А можите записать как в моем выше данном примере будет выглядить копирование в начало массива

Comment: А это с++/cli? Или что здесь делает знак ^???

Comment: Это Visual с++ консольное приложение CLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Инициализируем from, savedFrom в -1, savedLength, length в 0, индекс i в ноль.
2. Движемся вдоль массива, пока не встретим первое положительное число.
3. Устанавливаем from в значение i, равное индексу числа.
4. Движемся вдоль массива, наращивая lenght, пока не встретим неположительное число или конец массива.
5. Если length больше savedLength, сохраняем from и length в savedFrom и savedLength.
6. Если конец массива не достигнут, повторяем с шага 2.

После того, как получены начало и длина наибольшего отрезка положительных чисел, копируем их в начало массива.

Comment: @byte, Вы уверены, что надо просто копировать? В таком случае изменится содержимое массива, а не только порядок его элементов.

Видимо надо менять местами (SWAP) элементы найденной последовательности с элементами в начале массива. 

Точнее, просто менять можно, если последовательность отстоит от начала на расстояние не меньше ее длины. Тогда это делается просто, за один проход. 

Иначе надо делать циклический сдвиг (вращение) части массива от начала до конца последовательности на расстояние, задаваемое  индексом начала последовательности (уффф...).

Comment: Копировать не надо, необходимо при нахождении наибольшой последовательности перенести ее в начало массива, а из того места от куда ее перенесли должен происходить здвиг элементов вот как это должно выглядить:
 исходный  -8  -9   -4    1   -7   4    5   -6   -3  -10 
 конечный   4   5   -8   -9   -4   1   -7   -6   -3  -10

Comment: @avp Ваши уточнения верны, нужно именно обменивать последовательности.

Comment: Так в какой часте и что мне необходимо изменить если у меня уже есть запоминание максимальной длинны, но она переносится в конец. Разобраться никак не могу =(

Comment: @mishel, Вы хоть комментариев (только толковых) в код набросали бы (для переменных - где что находится). 

Думаете разгадывать, что Вы хотели изобразить и каких ошибок наделали все тут кинутся?

Навскидку, начало группы - это индекс `p1`, а `p2` последний индекс в ней. Если так, то сделайте (или найдите (в инете она есть)) функцию 

    rotate (int a[], int asize, int dist)

вращающую массив из asize элементов влево на dist (т.е. элемент с индексом dist после rotate() станет первым в массиве). И вызовете ее

    rotate (a,p2+1,p1);

Почему надо вызывать с такими аргументами, надеюсь, понятно.

Comment: Про то что все накинутся я и не думал. Про начало и конец группы верно. И нет ли более простого решения данной проблемы чем функция предложенная вами?

Comment: Очевидно, "в лоб" - можно выделить дополнительную память. 

Скопировать туда начало массива (до группы). Переписать группу в начало. Переписать копию на новое место в массив. Освободить память.
Скорость может быть и выше, чем при вращении (учтите, что правильная rotate() ([например отсюда](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/)) **не делает** dist циклов).

Что красивей, решать Вам.

Comment: Теперь осталось ток все это записать в коде, мдя сложновато для меня однако =)

Comment: @mishel, тогда открывайте новую тему. Эту-то закрыли... 

Попытайтесь сформулировать ее не как "Учебное задание", которые тут закрывают, видимо считая, что таким образом можно повысить средний уровень программистов.